# What is 6.280369834735099E-16 in just 3 decimal places? (Like x.xxx)

Tags: math, numbers, algebra, exponential

I just need the answer in 3 decimal places. How much is it?

Is the answer 0.628 or should I put 16 zero's before 6, in that case the answer might be 0.000 in 3 decimal places.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about maths and not about programming.

Comment: If you mean 3 decimal places in a fixed-point representation, then you are right, that would be `0.000`. Otherwise, `6.28*10^-16` (or using the C language notation variant `6.28E-16`), or maybe `0.628*10^-15`...

Comment: It is not off-topic, I put the tag "math" and not "Programming"

Comment: Before going to the trouble of adding the tag "math", did you stop to read that the tag says "Any math questions on this site should be programming related."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is  6.280369834735099E-16 aka 6.280369834735099*10^-16 aka 0.000000000000000628 therefor its almost zero aka 0.00

MFG
MiSt